# Prove/Disprove: Every two non-trivial NP-complete problems are decreasing reducible?

Tags: complexity-theory, turing-machines, computability, np-complete, reductions

We say that two languages $L_1,L_2$ are decreasing reducible if there exists a **polynomial time** reduction $f:\Sigma^*\to\Sigma^* $ and there exists $n\in\mathbb{N}$ such that for every $x\in\Sigma^*$ satisfying $|x|\ge n \implies |f(x)|\lt |x|$.

Assuming $P\ne NP$

> Prove\Disprove: Every two NP-complete languages $L_1,L_2$ are decreasing reducible.

I'd appreciate a hint or direction

Comment: What have you tried?  Can you explain the problem in your own words?

Comment: @PålGD I know every two NP-complete languages are polynomial reducible. Choosing some two NP-complete languages, I'd like to show they can not be decreasing reducible, i.e. for large enough $x$ the length of the image of $x$ decreases for every $x$.

Answer (score 4):

Let $L$ be any NP-complete language, and consider what happens when $L_1 = L_2 = L$. Given an instance $x$, by applying $f$ a linear number of times we would get that $x \in L$ iff $y \in L$, where $|y| < n$. Since there are only finitely many strings of length smaller than $n$, we can hardcode the correct answer for these strings, thus obtaining a polynomial time algorithm for $L$.